# Java: Sort List<List<T>> on basis of particular index

Tags: java, list, comparator

I am writing program to sort List>  (using Generics). However, not sure how to handle generic datatype in comparator.

This is what I have written so far.

```
public void sort(final int columnNumber){
    Collections.sort(this.listTable,new Comparator<List<T>>(){
        @Override
        public int compare(List<T> o1, List<T> o2) {
            int compareInt = 0;
            Object obj1 = o1.get(columnNumber);
            Object obj2 = o2.get(columnNumber);
            if(obj1.getClass().equals(obj2.getClass())){
                if(obj1.getClass().toString().endsWith(".String")){
                    compareInt = obj1.toString().compareTo(obj2.toString());
                }
                else if(obj1.getClass().toString().endsWith(".Integer")){
                    compareInt = (Integer)obj1 - (Integer)obj2;
                }
                else{
                    compareInt = obj1.toString().compareTo(obj2.toString());
                }

            }
            return compareInt;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Show us your code, please.

Comment: There is no research effort here. Even worse, there's no question either.

Comment: You handle a generic type just like any `Object`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use getClass().toString() to compare types.  Use instanceof and try to group types by common interfaces when possible.  For example CharSequence is a common interface for String, StringBuilder, and StringBuffer.

Here is one way.  You may want to rework the compare method to compare whatever types you have such as Date or URL or custom objects.

```
public class CompareEverything {

    public static void sort(List someList, int columnNumber) {
        Collections.sort(someList, new EverythingComparator(columnNumber));
    }

    public static class EverythingComparator implements Comparator<List<?>> {
        private int columnNumber;

        public EverythingComparator(int columnNumber) {
            this.columnNumber = columnNumber;
       }

        @Override
        public int compare(List<?> list1, List<?> list2) {
            Object obj1 = list1.get(columnNumber);
            Object obj2 = list2.get(columnNumber);
            return CompareEverything.compare(obj1, obj2);
       }
    }

    public static int compare(Object obj1, Object obj2) {
        int result = 0;
        if (obj1 == null) {
            result = (obj2 == null) ? 0 : -1;
        }
        else if (obj2 == null) {
            result = 1;
        }
        else if (obj1 instanceof CharSequence && obj2 instanceof CharSequence) {
            // String, StringBuilder, StringBuffer, etc.
            result = obj1.toString().compareTo(obj2.toString());
        }
        else if (obj1 instanceof Number && obj2 instanceof Number) {
            Number num1 = (Number)obj1;
            Number num2 = (Number)obj2;
            // Short, Integer, or Long
            if (isIntegral(obj1.getClass()) && isIntegral(obj2.getClass())) {
                result = Long.compare(num1.longValue(), num2.longValue());
            }
            else { // Float, Double, or any mismatched combo
                result = Double.compare(num1.doubleValue(), num2.doubleValue());
            }
        }
        // add other types...
        else {
            // mismatched types - compare as Strings
            // or maybe throw a RuntimeException?
           result = obj1.toString().compareTo(obj2.toString());
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static boolean isIntegral(Class<?> type) {
        return Short.class.equals(type) || Integer.class.equals(type) || Long.class.equals(type);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This helps a lot.

Comment: Like you have use CharSequence to handle various types of datatype such as String, StringBuffer etc,is there any similar class to handle Date related class?

Comment: ```java.util.Date``` is the parent class of ```java.sql.Date``` and ```Timestamp``` and such.  So you should be able to do this ```else if (obj1 instanceof java.util.Date && obj2 instanceof java.util.Date) { result = ((java.util.Date)obj1).compareTo(obj2); }```

Comment: Thanks.So in future if I am looking for any other such classes then I should be looking at parent class of all such classes?

Comment: If you can avoid duplicate code by comparing objects based on a common parent class, then yes.